# ancestor table class affects successor table elements

Tags: html, css

could someone tell me how to resolve problem of ancestor table class affecting successor table elements.

I have a table in table:

```
<table id="table1" class='parent'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and I have css settings:

```
.parent {
    background: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
#table1 tr:first-child td:first-child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    border: dashed red 1px;
}
```

this will result that table2 tr:first-child td:first-child will also get

```
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
border: dashed red 1px;
```

How can I avoid this and make css settings only for parent table, not affecting successor table elements

Comment: Please format your question carefully. You should also include your actual markup because it doesn't match your CSS and for all we know the problem may lie entirely elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use ">" for not to apply styles for nested tables

```
#table1>tr:first-child>td:first-child
```

or

```
#table1>tbody>tr:first-child>td:first-child
```

Comment: it didn't help. Already tried this. First td in parent table doesn't get formatting at this way.

Comment: Maybe you lost <tbody> tag on your code. Please check HTML in browser developer tools. #table1>tbody>tr:first-child>td:first-child

Comment: aaaahhh, damn <tbody> solved everything. I never using it while making tables in html code because it is not needed to make table. But obvious, it is needed in css targeting like this. Anyway, thank you a lot Anon